# Count number of cards stacked one over the other

Tags: deep-learning, counts

I have a stack of ATM cards and I want to count the number of cards available in the stack. How to proceed through it? I'm using Python 3.6.0 and opencv2. I'm attaching PNG file of the images. Kindly provide help in this direction.[[image: This image contains 28 cards stacked together.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PDxH.jpg)